# Cohort analysis for media site

Tags: data-mining, survival, case-cohort

I'm trying to find a reasonable way to measure **retention** of a site (news site). I'm trying to do cohort analysis: I've grouped all visits by year/week, and measured the percent of users that kept coming back in the following weeks.

**Clarification**: these users are first-time visitors, who have been tracked along the weeks following their first time visit.

I've got the following data:

```
yyyy/ww 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
201348  27.33   7.51    5.71    6.61    3       5.41    4.8     4.5     4.2     5.41    4.2     3.9     2.1
201349  7.88    5.23    3.03    2.53    4.02    3.16    3.13    2.83    2.63    2.16    2.06    1.25    
201350  7.91    3.79    3.01    4.59    3.57    3.48    3.08    2.93    2.45    2.25    1.4     
201351  6.64    4.1     5.69    4.41    4.13    3.68    3.36    2.8     2.56    1.56            
201352  6.09    6.99    5.05    4.79    3.99    3.79    3.24    2.94    1.84                
201401  11.66   6.69    6.28    5.45    4.67    3.74    3.4     1.99                    
201402  8.45    6.14    5.11    4.61    3.49    3.1     1.77                        
201403  9.45    6.27    5.38    4.12    3.57    2.08                            
201404  9.78    6.78    4.9     4.18    2.29                                
201405  8.96    5.37    4.45    2.47                                    
201406  8.88    5.85    3.07                                        
201407  8.46    3.76                                            
201408  6.29
```

The row labels are a week in time, the column labels are the number of weeks that passed since the first visit. The cell values are the **percent** of inital users that came back.

The two funky values at`week+1` account for christmas and new year. My question is: how should I interpret these values? I don't have a very deep statisical knowledge beyond the basics; I tried to calculate the slope of each row, and I got this (oldest to newest):

```
-4.956
-1.042
-0.788
-0.471
-0.64
-1.522
-1.145
-1.391
-1.758
-2.039
-2.905
-4.7
```

My rationale is that a good performing site would have an `increasing`slope value over time. In this case it seems the opposite. 
**Clarification**: What I mean with increasing slope is that the slope value would be less farther away from zero for the next first-time visitors; over time, the percentage of people who kept coming back would be higher (but still < 100% of course) than the previous cohorts.

Something like this, where you can see the fraction of retained users is bigger than the previous month: [image]

Any suggestions and/or critiques are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a cohort analysis which suggests that you are following a specific set of users, but you say the data represents "all visits by year/week." Can you describe the data more? If you're not limiting this to a specific set of users, then over time wouldn't you expect to see more one-time visitors? If you're not limiting this to a specific set of users, then you are not doing a cohort analysis. But I suspect that's not the issue. Also, if you're not already, it might be a good idea to constrain your analysis (or do a separate analysis) focusing on cohorts of first-time visitors to the site.

This is a kind of survival analysis: you say that you would expect an increasing slope over time, but I think it makes sense to expect the slope to be generally decreasing for any site. An increasing slope would mean that you have more people coming back for week two than week one, but presumably your best performance for week two would be to *retain* everyone who visited in week one, and realistically you're going to lose a few people. Looking further down stream, an increasing slope means that, looking at a specific group of people, more people from that group visited the site 5 months later than the week after their first visit. That'd be a pretty unusual expectation for a website.

The question is: at what value does the slope begin to plateau? This describes your consistent userbase.

Regarding those two rows with high values in week one, I'd suggest the following possibilities:

1. Those weeks your website presented especially interesting articles and brought a large percentage of users back the next week due to interest in your site.
2. Those were actually "slow news" weeks that brought fewer one-time visitors to the site than normal, and those high percentages indicate that a disproportionate number of the visitors that week are users of the site who would have come back again the following week anyway.
3. You had a slow week followed by a high traffic week due to some interesting content. Many users were brought back to your website not due to the week 0 content but due to the week 1 content, i.e. their week 1 visit was actually independent of their week 0 visit. If you shift the values for 201401 over 1 and treat week 1 as week 0, the values line up reasonably well with the other weeks. This does not hold for 201348.

I originally thought option 2 was more likely, but if it were the case we'd anticipate that high percentage to trickle over into the following weeks, not just week one. So I'd check the traffic you got those weeks and see if maybe your site published any particularly popular content those weeks. It's going to take some domain knowledge to really interpret this data, and it's your website not mine.

For your purposes, I don't think it would be unreasonable to take the mean down each column, giving the average retention N weeks out for each week. If you discount the first week as an outlier and then consider only out to a time period where you have at least 5 data points to consider (ignoring week 1), you'll observe a decay in retention out to week 8 where it hits about 2.7% percent.

I don't think taking the linear slope for each week as you have done makes much sense since your data isn't linear. If you really want you can fit a non-linear regression to your data, but I'm not sure how useful such a model would be to you.

Alternatively, you could keep tabs on the week 1, week 2 (... however far back you want to go) retention rates over time to try and determine the overall change in (new user?) retention for your site. It looks like the trend in these statistics is generally a decline, so maybe you should be concerned. If you wanted to plot a linear regression down each week (i.e. treating each column as a data series) I think that would make more sense than across rows. If you do this, you might want to start your regression at 201352 or 201402 since these weeks seem to be the start of your most consistent trend.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The users are indeed first-time visitors; I'll clarify that. I'll take the time to read through your answer and I'll post any more doubts!

Comment: "at what value does the slope begin to plateau?" this is great. I'll try and answer this question.

Comment: Also, for the record, survival analysis is not my expertise. If you research that specific topic, you may find some more tools and techniques relevant to your question.

Comment: I was hoping for a graph like this: http://blog.kepstatic.com/2012/05/twitter-cohort-example.jpg

Comment: It seems like you already have the data on hand to build this graph. The only difference is that you are defining a new cohort to follow every week instead of every month.

Comment: Yes, I meant I was hoping that my graph would also signal a good evolution over time. Unfortunately I think that's not the case; I have to clean up the data a little more.